# What else am I missing? I get an error : No suitable driver found for jdbc

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, jar

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

class test4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test4 connServer = new test4();
        connServer.dbConnect("jdbc:sqlserver:DESKTOP-TEST\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=TESTDB;integratedSecurity=true");
    }

   public void dbConnect(String db_connect_string)
   {
      try {
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string);
         Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
         String queryString = "select * from TESTTBL";
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Above is my code. I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc

On this line :

`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string);`

MS SQL server version is 2017.

Java and javac version is 11.0.3.

I added `mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11.jar` as external jar file. So it is in the Refrenced Libraries. Before adding it in reference, I had an error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver error on the line : Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");.

But now, I am having another error.

What else am I missing?

Comment: Can you paste pom.xml or build.gradle?

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. If you are confronted with a different problem after receiving answers, you should post a new question, not make your existing question a moving target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `//` between the driver name and the hostname:

```
connServer.dbConnect("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-TEST\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=TESTDB;integratedSecurity=true");
// Here -----------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out -

```
 DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver())
```

and Debug as Java Application to check if Driver is being loaded or not.

Comment: Tried it. Driver got loaded.

Comment: You shouldn't normally register drivers yourself. Drivers will register themselves if they are loaded.